# Putty, some bolded/color looks fuzzy/blurry

Tags: ssh, fonts, putty, colors

I'm not sure if this is supposed to be normal or what because I haven't used Putty in a while because I recently built a new development box. Of interest the graphics card is a R9 270X.

Notice how some of the text that is colored is fuzzy. 
[image]
The settings for colors are

[image]

Some confirmation on how colors look on your end/a solution would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Changing the font quality to "Antialiased" helped me:

[image: Font settings to update]

Answer (score 0):

It appears changing the font to indicate bold text make it look fuzzy/blurry, from memory and testing on multiple PC's. For now I changed it to indicate bold te[image]